# In applying for a UK visa, does VFS Silver Premium service include biometrics?

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

The link on vfs global site about this information doesn't work.
The only option left for me to buy premium service since its only working at 10 centers.

On the VFS global site I couldn't find any details. When I click on silver service on right side it says includes: which is blank.

Has anybody done premium service? If you use premium service do you do your biometrics and the submission of your passport and other documents at same time?

It would be nice if someone gives steps and what is included in service since its very expensive.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [VFS website](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/premium-services/silver-premium-package) the Silver Premium Package contains:

> - Priority Visa: Put your application at the front of the queue
> - Application and Document: Peace of mind that you have all the supporting documents required
> - Courier: Get your passport delivered directly to your home or office
> - SMS: Get instant visa application updates sent to your phone
> - Walk-in Without Appointment: Apply for a visa without booking in advance

It also states that your biometric collection is also included in all appointments:

> At the centre, you will also need to submit your fingerprints and
>   photograph. This is known as biometric information collection. A
>   digital finger scanner collects images of all 10 digits, and you will
>   have a digital photo taken.

When you go to the center you will submit all your documents, including passport and all supporting documentation, and have your biometrics taken.